# parse chr string into a dataframe using delimiters

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

My data is in a format, that looks like this:

```
t2 <- "a = 10\n   b = 2\n   c =20\n"
```

How can I parse it so that I get a dataframe that looks like this?

```
# a 10
# b 2
# c 20
```

I'm trying to use `readr::format_delim()`, but I'm happy to use any solution. The code below doesn't give me the right answer.

```
library(readr)
t2 <- as_tibble(t2)
format_delim(t2, delim = "\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `read.table` or the likes with `sep` argument.

```
read.table(text = t2, sep = "=")

#     V1 V2
#1    a  10
#2    b   2
#3    c  20
```

Or `read.csv(text = t2, sep = "=", header = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `fread` from `data.table`.  Would be faster

```
library(data.table)
fread(text = t2, sep="=")
#   V1 V2
#1:  a 10
#2:  b  2
#3:  c 20
```